# Using datetime in SQLite for getting values this month and last month

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an app which tracks money spent.  I have a function that gets all money spent for this month and last month.  It is one or the other, not both.  It is based on the parameter below called `lastMonth`.

Each transaction amount goes into my table with a transaction date.  I use a SQL query to total it up.  Like so:

```
 if (!lastMonth) {

            query += "WHERE ("
                        + "CAST(" + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP + " AS INT)/1000 >= CAST(strftime('%s', date('now','start of month')) AS INT)  "
                        + "AND "
                        + " CAST(" + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP + " AS INT)/1000 < CAST(strftime('%s', date('now','start of month','+1 month')) AS INT) ); ";

            } else {

                query += "WHERE ("
                        + "CAST(" + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP + " AS INT)/1000 BETWEEN CAST(strftime('%s', datetime('now','start of month', '-1 month')) AS INT)  "
                        + "AND CAST(strftime('%s', date('now','start of month')) AS INT) ); ";
            }
```

This *mostly* works.  But it seems to have trouble on the last day of the month.  For example, this question is being posted in August.  So the app dashboard currently shows all money spent in August, and July.

**The problem**:  All July 31st transactions (or whatever the last day of the previous month was) is going in the August total.  The July total does NOT include  July 31st.

**EDIT**

I am wondering if the SQL is correct, but I am putting the dates in database wrong. Here is the code for that:

```
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                timestamp = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: so for your int Month = pMonth; where are pyear, pMonth and pday defined/values set?  I would assume you could just use a format like yyyy-mm-dd instead of having to get the month name but I don't code in android just SQL and some C#

Comment: @Matt I double checked that, because that didn't make sense.  I accidentally displayed information stored in the DB meant for the user to see  -- which is formatted dates.  What I SHOULD have posted for you, it looks like I am simply passing in the Java-generated UNIX timestamp (as changed above) -- which is a pretty standard way of doing things; so, no.  I don't think that is the issue.  This is the value of `COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Well the obivious issue is the use of BETWEEN with the way your dates are identified.  It sounds like there may be additional issues surrounding time zones differences, how you are setting values, etc. we definitely do not have enough of your code here to do full debugging.  the definition and setting of the value for MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP  and example value(s) would be good because that is the next most likely culprit of your date comparison issues.

Comment: @Matt Well, I removed BETWEEN in favor of your code and it still responds the same way.  So maybe it is the data, like you say.  I will see if I can get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing the last day of the month is not the only issue with date/datetime values generally.

If you have a value on the last day of the month that was posted at noon.  It will not be counted if you compare just against the date without the date time.

You should do calculations like this where >= '01/01/2015 00:00:00 and where date < 02/01/2015 00:00:00.  That way all of the 1/31/2015 records are counted no matter what time they are time stamped at.  Or you can strip out the Month, day and year ignoring the time '20150101' and '20150131' as character strings on your comparisons.

Comment: I just updated the app in a way that I believe that may address this.  I am basically setting the datetime to 2016-07-31 00:00:00 (as an example).  The important part is adding the "0" to the H:i:s.  Does this get around the problem you mentioned above? (Edit:  I am using the time above, in a similar format and still converting to a unix timestamp of course)

Comment: Try converting everything to text.  In some standard 24 hour clock method with proper zero fills.  
"2015/01/01 12:00:03" is greater than
"2015/01/01 00:00:00" and thus included  
"2015/01/31 23:59:59" is less than
"2015/02/01 00:00:00" and thus included
This method gets you around issues where one database works one way and an OS works another way, and another database works another way.  Also note that some database or OS store the time from Grenich mean time.  So you may get a time like 12 noon but it's actually 11 pm from another day due to 13 hour difference from GMT.

Comment: I marked this correct because I noticed the problem in my question only appeared depending on when I added a new record depending on the time of day.  So it must be a time zone or another descripency with the users hours and how it grabbed the time (in Java).  I believe my actual SQL was correct.

Comment: To confirm where the issue is.  Run the sql with just sql, (no java code).  Insure you have tests cases a few minutes one either side of your query range in your database.  That is the best way to confirm if the problem is on the sql side.  If you can not get an error when doing this with just sql.  Then do the exact same tests from the Java code and see if you get different results.  (Thanks for the points).

Answer (score 2):

It is the use of BETWEEN that is making your LastMonth where statement inclusive of the more than 1 month.  BETWEEN is the same as >= AND <=.  So the issue when you say.

```
COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP >= [Start of Last Month]
AND COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP <= [Start of This Month]
```

Is that dates from more than 1 month are returned. All of Last Month and First Day of this month.

Another thought on your current month query, can you assume that the `COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP` will never be greater than `NOW`? If so you don't need to do anything but check if the `COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP is >= Start of Month.`

You could try something like the follows:

```
 if (!lastMonth) {

            query += "WHERE ("
                        + "CAST(" + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP + " AS INT)/1000 >= CAST(strftime('%s', date('now','start of month')) AS INT)  ";
            } else {

                query += "WHERE ("
                            + "CAST(" + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP + " AS INT)/1000 >= CAST(strftime('%s', datetime('now','start of month', '-1 month')) AS INT)  "
                            + "AND "
                            + " CAST(" + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP + " AS INT)/1000 < CAST(strftime('%s', date('now','start of month')) AS INT) ); ";
            }
```

Comment: Well, I get the same results as before.  I started thinking that maybe I am putting the wrong date in the DB.  So I added that code above as well if you care to look at.  EDIT:  Unless my Cast is killing the timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Compute the last day of the current month.
SELECT date('now','start of month','+1 month','-1 day');

Comment: this would not work if MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP  has a time component unless the time component is removed or if you select the last day of the month you actually select the last day at 23:59:59.999 and in sql-server anything above 23:59:59.997 actually rounds up to the first day of the month due to precision. I am not sure if that is also the case with SQLLite

Answer (score 1):

What results do you get if you select...

- MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP
- CAST(" + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GAS_UNIX_TIMESTAMP + " AS INT)/1000
- CAST(strftime('%s', date('now','start of month')) AS INT)
- CAST(strftime('%s', date('now','start of month','+1 month')) AS INT)
- CAST(strftime('%s', datetime('now','start of month', '-1 month')) AS
  INT)

...for transactions for the 30th and 31st of July and the 1st and 2nd of August?

Casting to INT and then dividing by 1000 will normally truncate your result as the divide will be acting on an integer (e.g. an integer 14680 divided by 1000 will give the answer 14). Is this your desired behaviour? If you multiplied the CAST(strftime) part by 1000 instead of dividing the TIMESTAMP by 1000 does it give the same results?

For consistency to help you debugging you might also want to consider using the same syntax both sides of your if/else (for example, use BETWEEN for both WHERE clauses) and you also swap between using date() and datetime() in your query which may also create unplanned results.

Comment: I am starting to think you might be on to something.  I dont even remember why I am casting, to be honest. I wrote that so long ago,